# Code Ingiter POST data empty

Tags: codeigniter, multipartform-data

I'm just have a trouble when POST a multipart form with codeigniter. The form is contain text field and 8 field of file upload. the problem is, the file is uploaded successfully with no error, but the field of text is empty in my controller.

I tried to print_r the POST data and get an empty array. But sometimes when I'm using google chrome, It's not got any problem.

Any solution?

Comment: Hard to guess, maybe you forgot to set name attribute field. Edit question and post form and controller code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form" action="some action page.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="text" name="inputfieldvalue"  value="Input Field">
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

// suppose your form is like this as above then to check textfield value

```
<?php echo $_POST['inputfieldvalue']; ?>
```

// pass the name attribute whatever you have given to $_POST[your name field value]. like this

Answer (score 0):

Complete example should be working.

your form target action to function `my_form` in `My_controller` controller. Lest try input with name `WTF`

```
<form name="form" action="my_controller/my_form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="text" name="WTF"  value="Input Field">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

your cotroller action in `My_controller.php` file (CI Controller folder) should look le this

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index(){

    /* do something for page my_controller if you want */

  } // end of index

  function my_form() { // = my_controller/my_form
   $here_is_it = $this->input->post('WTF'); // call value of input with name WTF

   /* test it */
   print_r($here_is_it);
  }
```

Extra, to make sure everything it's okay. You can Enable auto load feature in Codeigniter. [follow this tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)

Answer (score 0):

I Just check it for a while and the problem is not in the php or my html form code. But the problem is in my php.ini config. By increase upload max file size fix the problem. I just confused before because the form sometime work well and sometimes give an empty value.

Thanks in advance